# Custom behavior of "Start button" for custom project type

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, haskell, vs-extensibility

I write an visual studio 2015 extension to integrate the programming language Haskell.

I've already implemented the language service, syntax highlighting and a new project type - so you can create a Haskell-project which contains a *.hsproj file and a Main.hs file.

Now I need to override the behavior of the start button because I want to load all Haskell modules into the GHCi-Interpreter (the interpreter is also already integrated in visual studio as a new window).

The problem is that at the moment visual studio runs the msbuild process - but all I wanna do is to send programatically a command to my integrated interpreter ( :l Main.hs ) when the developer clicks on "start" or presses F5 - but only for my project type named "HaskellProject"!

If possible I want to replace the default build process for my project type - I do not need msbuild, I only want to load the files into ghci.

Has anyone any idea what I can do ?

Thank you and sorry for my english ;-)

Comment: I would start looking at the `Target` nodes in my *.hsproj file, this is how Visual Studio knows how to build the projects and also by the use of the Import node that looks something like this: `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />`.

Comment: Plus, your Haskell window could subscribe to the `BuildEventClass` events through `EnvDte` and load the files into the interpreter window... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._dispbuildevents_event.onbuildbegin.aspx That way you won't need anything int he MsBuild files.

Answer (score 1):

Launching a project via the F5 or Start menu, is done through your project system's I[VsDebuggableProjectCfg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsdebuggableprojectcfg.aspx) implementation.

I haven't dug into the new CPS project system, but if your project type is based off of CPS, the [Python Tools for VS repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS), might provide you with a good start.